# Make a wordpress category into a page

Tags: wordpress

So in wordpress, I have a list of pages in my navigation. Home - Videos - Blog

The "Home" shows every blog post regardless of category. How can I make the Videos and Blog show specifically every post from the "blog" category or the "videos".

Thanks
Greg

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com instead. This is a simple question that a google search should answer anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways.

First, this functionality is built into WordPress.  Every category can be called by a URL:

http://www.yoursite.com/category/category-slug/

The /category/ part of the URL is the WordPress default and you can change it under Settings | Permalinks in the Optional section.

The second way would be to create a custom page template and use the query_posts() function to include or exclude whatever categories you wish.  The syntax is:

```
query_posts( 'cat=1' );
```

To get all posts in category ID 1 (use Posts | Categories to get the ID numbers).  If you want a page with two categories:

```
query_posts( 'cat=1,3' );
```

To exclude a category and return everything else:

```
query_posts( 'cat=-5' );
```

query_posts() is pretty flexible and takes a bunch of different arguments.  You could do worse than to [read the Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress with BlueHost, click on Appearance -> Menus. Under "Menu Items," hit "Categories." Select the category you want to transform into a page and click "Add to Menu." The category will become a page on your menu. Now every blog post assigned to that category will appear only on the corresponding page.